# How to cache YUI DataSource?

Tags: ajax, yui, yui-datatable, yui-datasource

I'm setting up a YUI DataTable with filtering by following the steps on the [YUI site](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_localfilter.html)

However, I am using JSON as the DataSource ResponseType.  When I type in a value to filter, the request will be sent to the server again.  I find this to be wasteful as all the data has already been retrieved the first time.

Is there a way to cache the initial data returned and then filter only according to that data so another AJAX request does not have to be made?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the YUI 3 cache utility to cache the data in javascript memory or HTML5 localstorage object. You can read more about this at http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cache

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datasource/#caching should help.